# How to ensure MySQL replication is accurate?

Tags: mysql, database-replication, master-slave

I've recently used replication to back up my sql database. However when I compare table sizes they differ slightly. I find this odd as they contain the same number of rows.

I've read that this is due to the slave server being more optimized which is great. However it makes it difficult to know if anything has gone wrong.

would checking the slave periodically with

```
show slave status\G
```

be enough to check if there are any inconsistencies? This would show if there was an error or if one of the main threads had stopped.

I thought I could check the database size with

```
SELECT table_schema "Data Base Name", 
sum( data_length + index_length ) / 1024 / 
1024 "Data Base Size in MB", 
sum( data_free )/ 1024 / 1024 "Free Space in MB" 
FROM information_schema.TABLES 
GROUP BY table_schema ;
```

Is there an easier way of checking that the slave is identical with the master?

Comment: If you're doing statement-based replication there's no particular reason why the table files should be the same size in the first place.

Answer (score 2):

**To check the data integrity**

Use Percona's pt-table-checksum to verify the data integrity.

> pt-table-checksum performs an online replication consistency check by executing checksum queries on the master, which produces different results on replicas that are inconsistent with the master. The optional DSN specifies the master host. The tool’s “EXIT STATUS” is non-zero if any differences are found, or if any warnings or errors occur.

Source: http://www.percona.com/doc/percona-toolkit/2.2/pt-table-checksum.html

**To check whether the slave is running**

Do `show slave status` and check both `Slave_IO_Running` and `Slave_SQL_Running` are "**Yes**".

Answer (score 2):

This solution uses **awk** to process a show command output and sends a mail in case of errors in any of the field processed. In this case the fields are Slave_IO_Running and Slave_SQL_Running. Fill free to add other fields from the 'show slave status' output - Last_Error/Seconds_Behind_Master for example or to awk the output of other show commands.

```
 #!/bin/bash

 # get some slave stats

 Slave_IO_Running=mysql -u root --password="pwd" -Bse "show slave status\G" | grep Slave_IO_Running | awk '{ print $2 }'

 Slave_SQL_Running=mysql -u root --password="pwd" -Bse "show slave status\G" | grep Slave_SQL_Running | awk '{ print $2 }'

 Last_error=mysql -u root --password="pwd" -Bse "show slave status\G" | grep Last_error | awk -F : '{ print $2 }'  


if [ '$Slave_SQL_Running' == 'No' ] || [ '$Slave_IO_Running' == 'No' ];

 then

     echo "Last Error:" $Last_error | mail -s "Replication error on slavedb!!!" devops@company.com

 fi  

exit 0
```

I would not compare the size for many reasons but namely, because normally one day you would want to build your warehouse on top of the slave and read only from it for lets say .. internal reporting.
What I can suggest you though in this regard is to compare the size of the slave size (because this is what you should backup) per DB between last Backups. Sometimes seeing a very **big diff or a negative** one can lead you to some useful conclusions

Comment: So when -F isn't specified is the default field separator a whitespace char? Also I now know -Bse is -Batch,silent and execute (I'm new to bash!). This is a nice solution for checking the slave status. I would be doing this manually otherwise.

Comment: $man awk
....OPTIONS
       Gawk  accepts  the following options.  Standard options are listed first, followed by options for gawk extensions, listed alphabeti‐
       cally by short option.

       -f program-file
       --file program-file
              Read the AWK program source from the file program-file, instead of from the first command line  argument.   Multiple  -f  (or
              --file) options may be used.
.....
;)

Answer (score 0):

seconds_behind_master value should be less than 50 in the output of

show slave status\G;

Ideally zero value shows that slave is fully replicated.